# Using C++ non-static member functions as callbacks and class scope issue

Tags: c++, class, callback, function-pointers, static-members

My code contains the following:

1) A.h (cannot be changed by me as it's defined by somebody else)

```
typedef void (*fnctPtr)(int input);

class A
{
    A(fnctPtr func);  //Constructor for A
    //... Other details omitted
};
```

2) B.h (my code)

```
#include "A.h"

class B
{
    public:
      B() : m_a(m_private_method){};  //Ptr to non static method.

      void m_private_method(int input);
      A m_a;  //Member variable
};
```

3) A simple main.cpp declaring and instance of B

```
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

It does not compile, as m_a requires initialization with a fnct pointer of type void (*)(int input), not void (B::*)(int input).

Any advice on how to achieve what I want?

Thanks

Comment: The question is like "I need to cook a  steak dinner. I have a fish. How can I achieve what I want?"

Comment: Ok, to be more specific. Is there anyway to supply a non static member variable as an argument to a constructor that expects a prototype of: void (*)(...).  As I understand, a non static member function will always have class scope.

Comment: It's not about scope. It's about making sense. A member function isn't the same as a free function. You cannot *call* a member function. (You need to invoke it on an object.) The same way that a fish isn't a cow, even though both have eyes and smell.

Comment: Ok, I have worked around this, by declaring a free function and a pointer to an instance of B (assigned within the constructor for B). I'm then assigning the free function to the m_a variable in the intialisation list of B. Within the free function, I use the instance pointer to call the required function.  Was hoping that there is a less hacky way of doing it though

Comment: That's not hacky. That's basically what everyone does in this situation. It's OK.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's good to know (I'm fairly new to C++).  I just don't like the idea of having a static pointer floating around (pointing to my instance),  i'm trying to avoid any global state in my design.

Comment: Well, don't make it a global variable, but instead try to use some general "context" argument in your API (or redesign the API) to pass the instance information. But the *structure* of the approach is standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really stuck with `typedef void (*fnctPtr)(int input);`, then you have to provide a pointer to a function that takes a `int` as parameter and returns nothing.

When you' providing a pointer-to-member function of class `B` taking an `int` and returning nothng, you really provide either something that can be seen as:

- either function taking two arguments, the instance of the class`B` and an `int`.
- or a virtual function that need to lookup in `B` instance to know what function taking two arguments (`B` and `int`) to call.

There is no way to make any of those fit into the first definition.

You may find a hack (keeping an instance globally and using it inside an helper function would be one), but this is highly dependent of the full problem.